# Rotas com slim framework PHP

Tags: php, slim

Boa tarde, não tenho quase nenhum experiência com slim framework e estou dando uma estudada pelo [livroSlim](https://www.gitbook.com/book/johnidm/desenvolvendo-aplicacao-web-com-micro-frameworks-/details).
Fiz o download via composer e instalou a versão 3.8 e de cara teve algumas diferenças. Tentei criar uma rota simples, porém só funciona quando chamo o diretório raiz, caso eu chame a rota, tenho retorno 404, coloquei apenas um echo para ver se está funcionando.

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use \Slim\App;
    $app = new App();
    $app->get('/', function () {
        echo "index";
    });
    $app->get('/ola', function(){
        echo "teste com rota";
    });
    $app->run();
```

Comment: Está usando Apache ou php-standalone-server?

Comment: Usa algum .htaccess?

Comment: Não, na documentação não diz nada sobre isso.

Comment: Qual que é erro apesentado?

Comment: @JonathandeToni ele já disse `tenho retorno 404`, 404 é um status HTTP de página não encontrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estiver usando [**PHP Built-in web server**](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) basta navegar até a pasta `public` pelo CMD ou Terminal (depende do seu sistema operacional), supondo que esteja na pasta *Documents* (em windows), faça isto:

```
cd C:\Users\[nome do seu usuário]\Documents\projeto-slim\public
php -S localhost:8080 index.php
```

Pronto, deve funcionar, mas estiver usando apache terá que navegar até public, supondo que sua pasta seja `c:\xampp\htdocs\projeto-slim` ou `c:\wamp\htdocs\projeto-slim` ou `c:\apache\htdocs\projeto-slim`, você deve acessar via navegador algo como:

```
http://localhost/projeto-slim/public/
```

Claro que para remover o public da URL você pode usar um .htaccess ou virtualHost,

### `VirtualHost`

Para usar o `VirtualHost` edite o vhost.conf ou httpd.conf, deve ficar algo assim:

```
#Para acessar tudo que não use frameworks
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache\htdocs\"
    ....
</VirtualHost>

# para acessar seu projeto
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache\htdocs\projeto-slim\public\"
    ServerName meuprojetoslim.exemplo.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>

# para acessar seu segundo projeto
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache\htdocs\projeto-slim2\public\"
    ServerName meuprojetoslim2.exemplo.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

### htaccess

Se não puder editar pelo VirtualHost você pode tentar pelo .htaccess, crie um .htaccess na pasta raiz do teu site, com algo como:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meuprojetoslim\.exemplo\.com$ [OR] # sem www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.meuprojetoslim\.exemplo\.com$ # com www
RewriteRule ^ projeto-slim2/public/ [L]                        # o L é pra impedir conflitar com as próximas regras

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meuprojetoslim2\.exemplo\.com$ [OR] # sem www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.meuprojetoslim2\.exemplo\.com$ # com www
RewriteRule ^ projeto-slim2/public/ [L]                       # o L é pra impedir conflitar com as próximas regras
```

---

Claro que para o endereço `meuprojetoslim.exemplo.com` funcionar é necessário editar o `hosts` dentro da `system32` (isso tudo se for windows), então siga os passos:

1. desative o antivirus
2. Abra o notepad.exe como administrador
3. Aperte Ctr+O no notepad
4. Ao aparecer a janela de escolher arquivo digite isto `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` no campo `Nome:`

Vai aparecer isto (ou bem parecido):

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within dns itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
```

Adicione isto:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within dns itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       meuprojetoslim.exemplo.com
    127.0.0.1       www.meuprojetoslim.exemplo.com
    127.0.0.1       meuprojetoslim2.exemplo.com
    127.0.0.1       www.meuprojetoslim2.exemplo.com
```

Salve o documento, reative o antivírus, reinicie o Apache/Wamp/Xampp e então navegue pro endereço:

```
http://meuprojetoslim.exemplo.com
```

Irá acessar `c:\apache\htdocs\projeto-slim\public\`

Ao navegar para:

```
http://meuprojetoslim2.exemplo.com
```

Irá acessar `c:\apache\htdocs\projeto-slim\public\`

Ao navegar para qualquer outro endereço como: `http://localhost` ou `http://127.0.0.1`

Irá acessar `c:\apache\htdocs\`

Você pode criar um *VirtualHost* (ou um `RewriteCode`+`RewriteRule`) pra cada projeto assim.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, porém isso está anos luz do meu conhecimento..kkk..Coloquei um simples .htacess na raiz e funcionou. Quando baixa o slim nas versões mais antigas ^2.., esse arquivo vem por default, porém na nova não, sabe me dizer o motivo disso?

Comment: @RonaldoLopes não sei, provavelmente vc deve ter se confundido em algo, ou esqueceu de ativar ou mover algo.